# input argument structure of compiled matlab function called from c++

Tags: c++, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [compiled matlab file called from c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902887/compiled-matlab-file-called-from-c)

I went through the mcc example in MATLAB but something is not clear. Can someone please clarify? In the example we have:

```
function a = addmatrix(a1, a2) a = a1 + a2;
```

which after i compile using mcc results in a following definition in the c++ header file

```
addmatrix(int nargout, mwArray& a, mwArray& a1, mwArray& a2);
```

My question is if the output of the MATLAB function is a structure which contains a vector of dimension 1x5 and a matrix of dimension 7x3 then what should `nargout` be? And how should i define `mwArray a?`

Since the output of the MATLAB function is just 1 structure should `nargout` be equal to 1? And should I be defining `mwArray` as `mwArray a(1*5+7*3)` in my c++ code?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You do not explicitly define `nargout` in your Matlab code.  Rather it is defined implicitly by the number of values that your function returns.